# Rheem Hot Water Heater Leaking

Tags: hot-water

I have this water heater: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rheem-Performance-40-Gal-Tall-6-Year-36-000-BTU-Natural-Gas-Tank-Water-Heater-XG40T06EC36U1/205811145

It's only 4.5 years old (under its 6 year warranty). It's leaking in the back from underneath. The dripping is slow -- it fills up maybe a quart container per day. I can't see where it's leaking from -- it's somewhere underneath, maybe an inch from the sidewall.

I verified it's not leaking anywhere from the pipes on top, etc.

Is there anything that can be tried to fix this before I just replace it?

Comment: Since it's still under warranty, replacing it seems to be the most logical thing to do. If nothing else, you get a brand new water heater, and even if it only lasts as long as this one, you've got another 4.5 years before buying a new one and you know to steer clear of the brand (should you desire).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace.  If leaking from the tank it is finished.

The only leaks worth repairing on hot water tanks are from pipes/joints.

Tank leaks tend to get bigger over short time.